# Querying nested object in elasticsearch

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, mongoosastic

My mapping looks like the following:

```
    "mappings": {
        "nodes": {
            "properties": {
                "createdAt": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "data": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "isFile": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "isPublic": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "location": {
                    "properties": {
                        "_id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "owner": {
                    "properties": {
                        "_id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "username": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sharedWith": {
                    "type": "object"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I do the following query:

```
"filter": {
      "term": {
            "owner.username": "user_69d349"
      }
}
```

I get proper results, but when I do

```
"filter": {
    "term": {
        "owner._id": "RvdDC"
    }
}
```

I get no results.

I'm using the following document:

```
{
    "_index": "nodess",
    "_type": "nodes",
    "_id": "I7Cac9n",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": "stream",
        "isFile": true,
        "owner": {
            "_id": "RvdDC",
            "username": "user_69349"
        },
        "sharedWith": [],
        "isPublic": false,
        "location": {
            "_id": null
        },
        "data": "baked baked baked hey",
        "createdAt": "2015-03-24T00:53:53.551Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because you're not using `nested` type.

[Here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) is a great explanation what's going on when you're not using nested type. Basically your document is being flattened when you're indexing array of objects.

You have to tell ES that you're using nested type.

```
      "owner": {
            "type": "nested", //<-- declare type here
            "properties": {
                "_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Well, Im not using an array of objects. I'm just using object. See owner field in the example. I tried this already and didn't got much success.

Comment: The thing is that it is working with `owner.username`, but not working with `owner._id`

Comment: Have you check if your document is indexed properly? I mean there's actually `owner._id` field with that value.

Comment: yes, this is the result of http://localhost:9200/nodess/_search, I thought there is something specific with the underscore before name, but could not find anything about it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was about to say. It may be matter of `_id` field name which is kind of `reserved` for whole document ID.